# Javascript Regex: "Any word" pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In a Jasmine test, I am trying to set this match to fit with expressions like:

'Request `<any_word>` for `<any_word>` - Open actions menu'.

However, it's not being possible with this line, but Javascript doc says that `\\w` is the regex for any word:

```
expect(item.getIconToolTip()).toMatch('Request \\w for \\w - Open actions menu');
```

Any hint?

Comment: Define "word". Which characters should be allowed in a word? For example, is `risqué` a word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+` to repeat the previous token one or more times. `\\w` alone will match a single word character only.

```
expect(item.getIconToolTip()).toMatch('Request \\w+ for \\w+ - Open actions menu');
```

Comment: `\w+` won't match `risqué`, in that case you need to use `\S+`

Answer (score 3):

The special sequence `\w` matches any single word **character**, not whole words. You could use `\b\w+\b` to match a word, but defining exactly what a "word" is will be something you'll have to work out for your own purposes.